# What keymap do you prefer in ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, resharper

I am using ReSharper since version 3 and I always used InteliJ Idea/Resharper 2.x keymap schema. Recently I have learned Ilya's Visual Studio keymap. They each have advantages.

**What keymap do you use/prefer with ReSharper?**

Comment: Subjective questions are rarely accepted. Better make this a wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Resharper only for about 6-8 months. I use the Resharper keymap settings. They seem to be working fine for me until now. What is this iilya's keymap settings? Haven't heard of it so far :(

Comment: ReSharper comes with two keymaps: original named Resharper 2.x/IDEA and then another one created by Illya named Visual Studio. The second one should be more compatible with the standard Visual Studio shortcuts but in my opinion the IDEA is more natural. That's why I wondered what others are using.

Answer (score 0):

I started with R# 2.5 I got used to the IDEA commands, but when I take a PC that doesn't have R#, I'm lost with the VS shortcuts.
I've been lazy to learn the VS one and be able to do some work without R#

Comment: That's exactly my situation as well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the important thing is to pick a keymap and learn it well. Which one you pick doesn't really matter. There may be a slight benefit to learning the VS keymap so that you're in better shape when using VS on a machine that doesn't have R#.